# TTS tone - Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm making use of Text to Speech - TTS in my Android app..  I've pasted the code below.. TTS is working fine, however the voice/text it speaks is not very clear.. It speaks really quick, so that it is not fully understandable.. I tried setting Locale.US, and used setPitch or setSpeechRate but it is not really convincing. I felt that there is some problem with my phone (Samsung S2).. So tried installing Google Translate TTS app from Google Play store.. In that app the voice was really clear.

My app will be used by Kids.. so want to make sure that the voice is really clear.
I'm breaking my head for the past few days to fix this problem.. Would be great if you could give me some pointers on where I'm doing wrong or how to improve??

```java
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

        //tts.setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);
        //tts.setPitch(1.0f);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            speakOut(0);
        }

    } else {
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(
            TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }
}
private void speakOut(int position) {
    tts.speak("Some text goes here", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Note: I tried setting value as 0.5f,0.8f etc., in both setPitch and setSpeechRate but still all the voice is not really clear as in GoogleTranslate App.

Comment: Any pointers would be quite helpful..

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine.
All tts libraries are shared across the system. Samsung comes with its own tts library. Rest of phones use Pico TTS. The great thing is that your app is independent from the library and you can download as many TTS libs as you want so that when you request the TTS intent the user will be prompt a pop-up to select which of their TTS synth they want for your app.

For me Pico TTS was working fine. Velocity / speech rate was normal, I just put the tone (pitch) a bit up to de-robotize the feeling a bit.

```
tts.setPitch(1.1f);
```

Try with Pico TTS and answer back.

Comment: On that note, I recommend the Ivona voice (more specifically, their UK Amy voice) for the most human-like robotic voice I've ever heard. http://www.ivona.com/en/ By the way, I have no idea how much that voice actually costs for a developer. All that I know, is that as a user, they've allowed me to replace the default voice used by Google Navigation and other applications for free while their product is still in beta.

Comment: Nice info. Thanks Stephan!

Comment: @JoseLUgia Thanks for the response. I tried setting setPitch as 1.1f but the voice is still a bit fast. (I also setSpeechRate as 0.9f). I downloaded couple of apps from GPlay Store including Google Translate app. In those apps, the voice is pretty clear/slow and it doesn't sound robotic. BTW how do I make use of Pico TTS?

Comment: Try with bigger changes of the speechRate. Just for testing put 0.5 there so that you find a value which you feel comfortable with. You should be able to find it for download on Google Play. I'd also recommend that you download other tts libraries (search for "TTS" in Google Play and download a couple of them).
Note: When I search I can't find Pico TTS, I guess the reason is because I already have it installed on my device.

Comment: UPDATE: Searching for "tts engine" or "text to speech engine" gives better results. There are many of them.

Comment: @JoseLUgia I tried setting 0.5-1.0 in speechRate method, but it is not really convincing.. How come GoogleTranslate app works correctly (voice is clear) in my phone, when my app doesn't work properly??

Comment: Yeah, I struggled with the same things when developing my TTS app. Although in the end I wasn't seeing a huuge difference among both yet sensitive. Did you try other TTS engines? You'll see the difference there (it could be that Google is using their own one, that way it's easier to handle competency). I've heard good reviews about some engines like Vox, or the one Stephan mentions above.
Give it a try!

Comment: @JoseLUgia Is it possible to try other TTS engines through code?

Comment: Well it depends on the TTS engines that the user already has installed but if you can somehow control the devices into which your app would be installed you could do so. Think that this is triggered by an Intent which gives back a result with the selected Engine (the user is prompted a pop up with their possibilities to choose one - the same way as done for other intents like "Share" or open Google Play link). If you want to test it just install as many tts engines as you want in your test device and choose one at a time (remember to Wipe data of your app to reset the last tts engine selected)

Comment: @JoseLUgia thanks for the detailed explanation (+1 for your answer :)) quick question: I didn't install any TTS engine in my app till now. How come the voice in GTranslate app is very slow and clear(not robotic) compared to my app??

Comment: I'd say they are using a different engine. We'll have to ask them directly :)

Comment: haa haa.. I've friends in Google.. will check with them :)

Comment: There you go, you don't need StackOverflow!